# Handling rate limit exceptions with Cursor in tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to find the correct way to handle rate limits when iterating through a list of followers using the Cursor object. Here is what I'm trying:

```
while True:
    try:
        for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=root_usr).items():
            print(follower.id)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        # hit rate limit, sleep for 15 minutes
        print('Rate limited. Sleeping for 15 minutes.')
        time.sleep(15 * 60 + 15)
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This is probably incorrect, since an exception will make the `for` loop start from the beginning again. What's the right way to iterate through all of `root_usr`'s followers while also handling the rate limit problems?

Comment: the `for` loop should be above the try/except clause that way it tries on a per user level as opposed to the whole loop overall

Comment: But isn't it `tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=root_usr).items()` that will throw the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the `Cursor` instance on a variable and call `next(cursor)` inside a try-catch. You can handle StopIteration and TweepError's that way.

Like

```
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=root_usr).items()
# or tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=root_usr).items().iter()
while True:
    try:
        follower = next(cursor)
        print(follower.id)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        # Handle this, sleep, log, etc.
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example under the [code snippets section of the documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.10.0/code_snippet.html#handling-the-rate-limit-using-cursors) that suggests making a wrapper function to deal with error handling.

```py
def limit_handled(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(cursor)
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            time.sleep(15 * 60)
        except StopIteration:
            print("Done")
            break


for follower in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=root_usr).items()):
    print(follower.id)
```

Also, I suggest setting count to the max, `tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=root_usr, count=200).items()`, to make the most of each API call.